# Ireland Visa Waiver program – minimum time in the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, ireland

I'm an Indian passport holder with a UK Short Stay "C" visa issued in the US. My visa does not have a BIVS endorsement. I understand that I can travel to Ireland without an Ireland visa, as long as I land in the UK first, using the [the Short Stay Visa Waiver program](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/coming-to-visit-ireland/short-stay-visa-waiver-programme/).

Is there a minimum amount of time I need to spend in the UK before heading over to Ireland?

My preference is to land in LHR, complete immigration, and take a flight to DUB without leaving the airport. I want to make sure that there is no issues with that.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

In the page you link to it says:

> In order to avail of the programme you must have *landed and gained lawful entry to the UK* on foot of your current UK visa, prior to undertaking the journey to Ireland.

There are no other conditions mentioned. Irish immigration can't tell if you left the airport or not, as long as you cleared UK immigration.

Comment: It is perhaps worth saying that "*on foot of*" is a Hiberno-English idiom meaning "*because of*" and does not require you to enter the UK by walking.  It is astonishing that the Irish government thinks people in the rest of the world could understand this.